# Plotting an integral of a function in Octave

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, octave

I try to integrate a function and plot it in Octave.
Integration itself works, i.e. I can evaluate the function `g` like `g(1.5)` but plotting fails.

```
f = @(x) ( (1) .* and((0 < x),(x <= 1)) + (-1) .* and((1 <x),(x<=2)));
g = @(x) (quadcc(f,0,x));

x = -1.0:0.01:3.0;
plot(x,g(x));
```

But receive the following error:

```
quadcc: upper limit of integration (B) must be a single real scalar
```

As far as I can tell this is because the plot passes a vector (namely `x`) to `g` which passes it down to `quadcc` which cannot handle vector arguments for the third argument.

So I understand what's the reason for the error but have no clue how to get the desired result instead.

N.B.
This is just a simplified version of the real function I use, but the real function is also constant on a finite set of intervals ( number of intervals is less than ten if that matters).
I need to integrate the real function 3 times in succession (f represents a jerk and I need to determine functions for acceleration, velocity and distance). So I cannot compute the integrals by hand like I could in this simple case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, Octave integration routines only take scalars as lower and upper integration boundaries. So you cannot pass the vector x = -1.0:.01:3.0 as an argument.

Possible solutions:

Use a for loop, e.g. 
y = x;
for j = 1:length(x) y(j) = g(x(j)); end;
plot(x,y)

... which will waste a lot of cycles ...
... or ...

Use a low end integration routine such as the midpoint rule (you're plotting the results, right? Why use quadcc?) and write your own quadrature routine that accepts vector arguments.

Comment: it's been so long since I asked this question, I don't remember the use case any more ;-). The only thing I remember is that I switched from Octave to C#... Thanks anyway for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cumtrapz instead of quadcc.

Comment: How would you rewrite the function `g`?
`g = @(x) (quadcc( 0:0.1:x, f(0:0.1:x)));` doesn't work.
The plot results in an error ` __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is valuable to answer this question at this moment, but it is indeed a valuable question in terms of how to use (and think in terms of) GNU Octave.

GNU Octave is based on vector and matrices.

We have a function $f$

```
f = @(x) ( (1) .* and((0 < x),(x <= 1)) + (-1) .* and((1 <x),(x<=2)));
```

which, in terms of GNU Octave, is a **vectorized** function (i.e. if $x$ is a vector, then $f$ is also a vector).

In order to plot the integral of $f$, we have to understand its integral $g$ must be also a vector. The problem is here that function `quadcc` is not vectorized, you cannot enter an $x$ which is a vector into `quadcc`. To my knowledge integration procedures are given most of the time in scalar form (not vectorized!).

To do what is demanded in the question above, the simpler way is recurring to a loop, e.g. defining $g$ as following

```
function y = g(x)
  f = @(x) ( (1) .* and((0 < x),(x <= 1)) + (-1) .* and((1 <x),(x<=2)));  
  y = [];
  for i = 1:length(x), 
    y = [y; quadcc(f,0,x(i))];
  end
end
```

This way you have a vectorized version of the integral of $f$.